# how to get span text from inner tags using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

I want to get the span text using jQuery so my html code is like below

Note :- actually this logic was in table data so I given example code only.

```
<div class="strategiesddata">
<div class="strattabletodivmobright">
<p class="stategybuysellchkbox clearfix">
<span class="BUY active" name="spbuy">B</span>
<span class="SELL " name="spsell">S</span>
</p></div>

<div class="strattabletodivmobright">
<p class="stategybuysellchkbox clearfix">
<span class="BUY " name="spbuy">B</span>
<span class="SELL active" name="spsell">S</span>
</p></div>
</div>
```

In the above html code I have two active, buy or sell div's so my query is if it active span then I should take that span text

ex:- From first div B and next div S text I should take

For this I have written jQuery like this

```
$(".strategiesddata").each(function () {
 t = $(this);
var tst = t.find(".stategybuysellchkbox").closest(".active").html();
});
```

And

```
$(".strategiesddata").each(function () {
 t = $(this);
var tst = t.closest(".stategybuysellchkbox").find("span[.active]").html();
});
```

But I'm getting the value is `undefined` Suggest me where I did the mistake and how to achieve this?

Comment: What is `t` in those examples?

Comment: Hi @Phil t is ` t = $(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery statement is wrong, try this.

```
var tst = $(".stategybuysellchkbox").find(".active").text();
```

Answer (score 1):

To reference the elements in question, you should be able to simply use

```js
$(".stategybuysellchkbox span.active")
```

One issue here is that jQuery's methods like `text()` and `html()` will only get you the contents of the first element in the collection.

To get an array of all the text, use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```js
const activeText = $(".stategybuysellchkbox span.active")
  .map((_, span) => span.textContent).get();

console.log(activeText);
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="strattabletodivmobright">
<p class="stategybuysellchkbox clearfix">
<span class="BUY active" name="spbuy">B</span>
<span class="SELL " name="spsell">S</span>
</p></div>

<div class="strattabletodivmobright">
<p class="stategybuysellchkbox clearfix">
<span class="BUY " name="spbuy">B</span>
<span class="SELL active" name="spsell">S</span>
</p></div>
```

---

You definitely don't need jQuery for this either

```js
const activeText = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll(".stategybuysellchkbox span.active"),
  (span) => span.textContent
);
```